# Trying to run Modal component VueJS in existing project

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, box

I made a separate .vue file, where I have put the "template" of the Modal Box and the required CSS(later I will move it to the main.css). The functionality which I need is - being on the main page Data.vue, the client clicks on the button and opens up a Modal Box, where he/she can write a message and send it to us.

***modalTest.vue***

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style>
  .modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: table;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
  }

  .modal-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .modal-container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .modal-header h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #42b983;
  }

  .modal-body {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

  .modal-default-button {
    float: right;
  }

  .modal-enter {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .modal-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .modal-enter .modal-container,
  .modal-leave-active .modal-container {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
</style>
```

I added the button which I need to click in order to popup the Modal Box in one of the pages of the project.

**Data.vue**

```
<template>
...
a lot of divs
...
<button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
...
</template>

<script>
  export default {

}
</script>
```

And last but not least the 
***main.js***

```
import modalTest from './components/modalTest'

Vue.component('modal', modalTest);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  data: {
  showModal: false
  }
});
```

That's what I managed to do until now. However, when I click on the button, which is in the page Data.vue, nothing happens. Looking at the console there is no information regarding the problem. Maybe I am mistaken something very stupid, but I can't find anything wrong for now.

Comment: you should have `showModal: false` in Data.vue since you are using it there not in the root vue  instance in main.js

Comment: Does it have to be in data() { return { showModal: false} } like that? Right now I am getting the error Property or method "showModal" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: yes it has to be in `data`

Comment: Oh, yeah managed to run it. How to make the window to close when it's clicked the button send?

Comment: Is there any possibility to put the template of the Modal box in existing .vue file? Where there is already a <template>...</template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the showModal: false in the return of data of the childs page fixed the problem :) Thanks to @Vamsi Krishna